# Am I using the wrong jquery to run fancybox?

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

HTML in head tags

```
<link href="../css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/expandtag.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fancybox.js"></script>
```

As you can see I'm running jquery 1.11.1 and downloaded fancy box from Lokesh's website as is from today, I'm assuming that it's the latest version. I changed the image routes in the lightbox.css file from img to images which is the folder I'm using in my site and is the destination i put the file. I also placed the .js file in my site's js folder. I applied the rel="light-box" attribute to my image hrefs on the page that I want lightbox applied. When I preview it in Chrome however, nothing happens when I click on the thumbnail. Any suggestions?

Comment: show us the js code you use to invoke lightbox

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Not sure if that's the kind of fiddle you're after. What did you mean by invoke the lightbox?

Comment: @EbenHafkamp the js code you use to fire lightbox on click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rel: attribute was not working on my images because the jquery trigger was looking for a class called .fancybox and also it was only going to work on links. I had to link my thumbnail to itself and on the linked version of itself place the class .fancybox. I also discovered that placing the jquery for linking elements to fancybox code is best placed at the bottom, just before the body tag for performance purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's difficult to help with the amount of setup needed to make something like this work.  Typically if a JavaScript plugin does not work you should check the source of your page.  When you click on the external JavaScript and CSS files associated with the plugin are they all pulling up?

If so, than make sure you are inserting the actual Script that will run the code for your plugin which exists within your external JavaScript pages.

Fancybox gives examples of multiple ways to fire your lightbox. Something like this needs to be added to your HTML page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* This is basic - uses default settings */

    $("a#single_image").fancybox();

    /* Using custom settings */

    $("a#inline").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true
    });

    /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */

    $("a.group").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });

});
</script>
```

Obviously this has several different ways of firing your lightbox and you don't need all of those options.  the group one is where I would start.  Make sure your image looks like this.

```
<a class="group" rel="group1" href="image_big_1.jpg"><img src="image_small_1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

If this still does not work you want to pull up your site in chrome.  Right click and select inspect element.  Inside the inspector console click the console tab and this will most likely display something in red stating where the JavaScript error could be.

Comment: Thanks for your help i was unsure where to paste the ("#id").lightbox_me(); code. So in a script tag in the header?

Comment: actually good thing you asked, sometimes the lightbox does not work because the code fires before the page is loaded.  therefore the items it's looking for aren't loaded yet.  I would put both your Jquery script and the lightbox script just before the closing </body> tag.  Make sure your script in the header is put inside the $(document).ready(function () { -->inside here }); because that will ensure the code is not fired until the javascript plugins and page is loaded.

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean by the source? By clicking on the external js and css files, they should pull something up? I'm not sure what that means. The external files that I downloaded are sitting in my sites root folders in their respective js and css locations. I don't need to change the actual code inside those do I? I have made sure the link in the script tag that calls them from their locations are spot on and it identifies that the path is correct within dreamweaver. I think where I'm having the most trouble is incorporating jquery into the elements that I want to show up in lightbox.